# Comparison operator with boolean always returning false

Tags: javascript, html, string, comparison, string-comparison

I'm trying to understand objects and functions, this is my code:

```
function house(roof) {
  this.roof = roof;
  this.roofdescrip = describehouse();
}

function describehouse(){
  var z = this.roof;
  x="The house has a roof.";
  y="The house does not have a roof.";
  if(z===true){return x;}
  else{return y;}

  }

var myhouse = new house(true);



document.write(myhouse.roofdescrip);
```

always returns

```
The house does not have a roof.
```

whether I change the parameter to true or false. Why?

Comment: Triple = compares type too. Not sure if this is the problem, but here you compare a roof to a boolean?

Comment: `describehouse` is not a *method* of `myhouse`, so `this` doesn't work when you call it like that

Answer (score 0):

That's because the `this` operator in `describehouse()` function points to the window object which will have `roof` equal to `undefined`, try passing the `this` as a parameter. 
Something like this

```
function house(roof) {
  this.roof = roof;
  this.roofdescrip = describehouse(this);
}

function describehouse(that){
  var z = that.roof;
  x="The house has a roof.";
  y="The house does not have a roof.";
  if(z===true){return x;}
  else{return y;}

  }

var myhouse = new house(true);

document.write(myhouse.roofdescrip);
```

Comment: What does the 'this' in the describehouse function point towards?

Comment: 'this' points to the caller of the method, in your case it was the global window object not the house object, if you want to see it a little clearer, write {{ var roof = true; }} outside any of the functions, that way the window object will have 'roof' equal to true and 'z' will be true

Answer (score 0):

The problem is related to the scope. In your case, `this` inside the `describehouse` function is actually the `window` object. If you try to log `this.roof` inside the function, you will get `undefined`. `undefined` is considered faulty and that is the reason you always get the same result.

To make your code work, you need to bind the function to your object and then call the function.

```
function house(roof) {
  this.roof = roof;
  this.roofdescrip = describehouse.bind(this);
}


function describehouse(){
  var z = this.roof;
  console.log(this)
  x="The house has a roof.";
  y="The house does not have a roof.";
  if(z===true){return x;}
  else{return y;}

  }

var myhouse = new house(true);

document.write(myhouse.roofdescrip());
```

Here I put another way to do it.

```
class House {
  constructor(roof) {
    this.roof = roof
  }

  describeHouse() {
    const verb = this.roof ? "has" : "does not have"
    return `The house ${verb} a roof.`
  }
}

const myHouse = new House(true)
const otherHouse = new House(false)
console.log(myHouse.describeHouse()) // "The house has a roof."
console.log(otherHouse.describeHouse()) // "The house does not have a roof."
```